# Basic Assembly Programming Language for MAC OS X

Tags: macos, assembly

I'm currently trying to learn Assembly for *Mac OS X* (I'm using Yosemite Beta 5 at the moment). There aren't that many good tutorials out there, but I've been using [this one](http://orangejuiceliberationfront.com/intel-assembler-on-mac-os-x/). While trying to add numbers, this is my current code (which doesn't work):

```
section .text
.globl start
start:
    push dword hellolen
    push dword hello
    push dword 1
    mov eax, 0x4
    sub esp, 4
    int 0x80    

    pushl %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    subl    $24, %esp
    movl    $3, (%esp)
    call doStuff

    push dword 8
    push dword %eax
    push dword 1
    mov eax, 0x4
    sub esp, 4
    int 0x80    

    add esp, 16
    push dword 0
    mov eax, 0x1
    sub esp, 4
    int 0x80

.globl doStuff
doStuff:
    movl    8(%ebp), %eax
    addl    4(%ebp), %eax
    ret

section .data
    hello db "12345", 0xa
    hellolen equ $-hello
```

Comment: You appear to have a mixture of Intel (Nasm?) and AT&T (Gas) syntax. Which one are you trying to use?\

Comment: `push dword hellolen` is Intel syntax and `pushl %ebp` is AT&T syntax. And why don't use x86_64?

Comment: Well I would like to do this on OS X. I can't really tell the difference between each syntax. A link to a suitable guide that can clearly explain this problem or a solution to this program would be really appreciated.

Comment: There you are! I thought you were gone. I'd suggest a new question, explaining more what you want to do. For Nasm, there's the Nasm Forum (forum.nasm.us) - it's a PITA to get signed up. For Gas... I dunno... Your tutorial (such as it is) is for Gas.